# WCF forces to connect to net.tcp on production server, altought httpBasicBinding is setup

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, azure, tcp

Hi I have a wcf service on azure server.

Each time I try to use live service on azure server it throws me an error that I have to log in or similar:
[image]

When I use local service it works, as soon as I publish service on production server it tries to connect with net.tcp protocol. Why is that?

My web.config for service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
    <!--
      In the example below, the "Replace" transform will replace the entire 
      <customErrors> section of your web.config file.
      Note that because there is only one customErrors section under the 
      <system.web> node, there is no need to use the "xdt:Locator" attribute.

      <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
        mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>
    -->
  </system.web>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
        switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
        propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Runtime.Serialization" switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="App_tracelog.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Client:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPostDataService" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760" />
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <!--<endpoint address="http://localhost:23738/Post/PostDataService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPostDataService" contract="Web.Service.Post.IPostDataService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IPostDataService" />-->
      <endpoint address="http://someservicesubdomainthatIedited.azurewebsites.net/Post/PostDataService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPostDataService"
                contract="Web.Service.Post.IPostDataService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IPostDataService" />  
  </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I don't think it's your service that has an issue - look at the address in error box: `net.tcp://xxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net:4016/Microsoft/VisualStudio/msvsmon` - it looks like an issue with the remote debugger.  I haven't worked with Azure, so not sure what your next step would be, but issues with net.tcp connections can (and often are) be related to firewalls blocking the port.

Answer (score 0):

You need a system.serviceModel >> Services >> Service element in the service config that actually specifies which binding & bindingConfiguration to use (similar to what you have in the client, unless you are doing it in code:

```
<services>
  <service name="Web.Service.Post.IPostDataService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPostDataService" contract="Web.Service.Post.IPostDataService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: I don't think this is the reason for his issue.  In .NET 4.0+, `basicHttpBinding` is the default and a default endpoint will be created without the need to specify it in the config file.  See this link for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx